# Problems building firebreath with external boost

Tags: firebreath

I'm trying to use boost 1.46.0 with firebreath. I have read the firebreath wiki on building with external boost but haven't been able to figure it out.

I downloaded boost to ~/boost_1_46_0 and compiled it with bjam. I call prepmake.sh like so:

```
prepmake.sh projectdir builddir -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release" \
     -DVERBOSE=1 \
     -DWITH_SYSTEM_BOOST=1 \
     -DBOOST_ROOT="~/boost_1_46_0/" \
     -DBoost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=on \
     -DBoost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME=off
```

Prepmake succeeds. I then call make in the firebreath build directory but run into linking errors toward the end.

```
Linking CXX shared library ../../bin/Test/npTest.so
../../ScriptingCore/libScriptingCore.a(URI.cpp.o): In function `global constructors keyed to URI.cpp':
URI.cpp:(.text+0x637): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
URI.cpp:(.text+0x643): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
URI.cpp:(.text+0x64f): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
URI.cpp:(.text+0x65b): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
../../ScriptingCore/libScriptingCore.a(URI.cpp.o): In function `FB::URI::isLocalhost() const':
URI.cpp:(.text+0x3065): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
URI.cpp:(.text+0x3095): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
URI.cpp:(.text+0x32ed): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
../../ScriptingCore/libScriptingCore.a(URI.cpp.o):URI.cpp:(.text+0x3569): more undefined references to `boost::system::system_category()' follow
```

Thanks -Darren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to set the boost libraries firebreath uses in my project's PluginConfig.cmake:

```
add_boost_library(date_time)
add_boost_library(regex)
add_boost_library(system)
add_boost_library(thread)
```

Weird thing is it seems like firebreath finds them automatically (see below) but unless I manually specify add_boost_library the linker isn't aware of them:

```
-- Boost version: 1.46.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   thread
--   system
-- Boost version: 1.46.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   thread
--   system
--   date_time
-- Boost version: 1.46.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   thread
--   system
--   date_time
--   regex
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

Comment: There may be an issue somewhere with the way firebreath's cmake is dealing with external boost libraries; I don't use that branch of the code myself and thus am uncertain of the details.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're missing the boost-system library

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @taxilian. You were right I was missing the boost-system library. I thought firebreath would be able to find them automatically but I had to specify the firebreath boost dependencies through add_boost_library.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar issue where (using external boost 1.56 on windows with VS2013) the linking failed saying it can't find the libraries for boost date_time and regex.

Adding them using

```
add_boost_library(date_time)
add_boost_library(regex)
```

had no effect, however this fixed the problem for me:

```
link_boost_library(${PLUGIN_NAME} date_time)
link_boost_library(${PLUGIN_NAME} regex)
```

For future references in case anyone stumbles upon this issue.